# batch replacing apostrophe character

Tags: batch

I have a script (using cmd.exe w8) that retrieve the wallpaper path from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper`

I then put the path of the wallpaper in a variable but if the path of the wallpaper contain this character `’` (U+2019), it will get replaced by `'` (U+0027).

This is messing with my xcopy command that I use afterward.

Example:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2,* skip=2" %%L IN (
    `reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper`
) DO SET _pathWallpaper=%%M
```

the path in the registry is

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Fond d’écran.bmp
```

but it will save the path as

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Fond d'écran.bmp
```

Notice the apostrophes in the filename

Comment: Please add the essentials of your batch file to your question, so that we may investigate where the replacement occurs. And of course tell us which batch processor you are using.

Comment: it is done, am using cmd.exe

Comment: I have looked at this in detail. The problem is that `cmd` doesn't handle Unicode strings properly: when output is redirected or piped to another process (implicit in your `for /f`) it is converted to ASCII. `PowerShell` has better handling, but I'm no expert and I have not so far managed to find an equivalent. What I have found is that `reg export "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" tmp.reg` will output the correct Unicode text, but I haven't found Unicode parsing and other handling tools, though this should be possible within PS. I'll keep looking, but I doubt `xcopy` will be usable.

Comment: I suspect that the only way you're going to solve this is by: (1) implementing something equivalent to `xcopy` within PowerShell; (2) writing a program to do what you want; or (3) taking the easy option and rename the file to use ASCII characters only - if you don't have a large number of such file names, then this is probably the best work-round. See [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/08/25/powershell-output-redirection-unicode-or-ascii/) for more information on Unicode in PS.

Comment: @AFH The simplest solution is just to change the code page. See my answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I did experiment with `chcp 65001`, but it still didn't seem right. When I tried to look at what was in the variable, `echo` looked OK on screen, but saving to a file gave an extended byte sequence which did not reproduce correctly when listed. However, I tried your answer, but replacing `echo` with an `xcopy` command, and it did indeed work, which my experiments had not led me to expect, hence my pessimistic comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `for` replaces `’` (U+2019) with `'` (U+0027)

You can work around this by using [chcp](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) to change the code page UTF-8:

```
chcp 65001
```

To demonstrate I've created the following batch file `test.cmd`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo use UTF-8 code page
chcp 65001
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%l in (`dir /b *.bmp`) do (
  echo %%l
  )
echo use default code page
chcp 850
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%l in (`dir /b *.bmp`) do (
  echo %%l
  )
endlocal
```

And the following file:

```
> dir /b *.bmp
Fond d’écran.bmp
```

Output from running `test.cmd`:

```
> test
use UTF-8 code page
Active code page: 65001
Fond d’écran.bmp
use default code page
Active code page: 850
Fond d'écran.bmp
```

You can see that `’` is not replaced when using a UTF-8 code page.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [chcp](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) - Change the active console Code Page. The default code page is determined by the Windows Locale.

Comment: thank you, that was it. I found the answer minutes before I saw your response. Although Im using chcp 1252

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for this problem would be to simply rename the file to something that did not have the apostrophe in it. However, there is something else you could do to keep the apostrophe in the file name.

You could try replacing the apostrophe after you save the file path to a variable. Here is an example.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set string=C:\Your'e path here
set find='
set replace=’
call set string=%%string:!find!=!replace!%%
echo %string%
```

The output of this script would be `C:\Your’path here`, you could adapt this into your script to replace the `'` with `’`. However, if this does not work you may have a problem with the character set you are using. Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: The simplest solution is just to change the code page. See my answer.